# Connecting SQL Server with ASP.NET using Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2012, connection-string

I am getting below exception while connecting ASP.NET with SQLSERVER using below connection strings.i tried two methods.

Exception

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL

Connection String

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con;
            con = new SqlConnection("Server=ADMIN/SQLEXPRESS,Database=test,integrated security=true");
            con.Open();

        }

              (or)

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con;
            con = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=test;integrated security=sspi");
            con.Open();

        }
```

i am connecting SQLSERVER directly by using below server name in windows authentication.It is connecting well but it is not connected from asp.net

Server Name:ADMIN\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting "Cannot Connect to Server - A network-related or instance-specific error"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci)

Comment: Remember that IIS (and IISExpress too) runs using a different user than yourself

Comment: Your top connection string is mangled: uses / not \, uses commas not semicolons. Your bottom connection string is mangled - doesn't cite an instance name, required for SQL Express

Comment: try this `connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=YourDataBaseName;Integrated Security=True;"`

Answer (score 1):

A connection string for  SQL server should be like this: `"Server=localhost; Database=Testdb; Integrated Security=True;"`
and If you have Named Instance e.g **localhost\SQLEXPRESS**

```
Integrated Security=?
```

When false, User ID and Password are specified in the connection. When true, the current Windows account credentials are used for authentication.
Recognized values are `true, false, yes, no, and SSPI (strongly recommended),` which is equivalent to true.[check connectionstrings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/)